# How to get average value from array of array of objects with dates?

Tags: javascript

I trying to display  data in chart.js and I need to get average value by hour for month.For instance, average value at 1 pm, at 2 pm for whole month .  I have an array of arrays of objects. Each array of object are day of the month. It has date by hour and value assigning to it. So 24 hours and 24 values for each array of object.

[image]

```
const countHours = (() => {
  const hours = []
  let total = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++) {
    const day = arrayOfDays[i]
    for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
      total += day[i].y
    }
  }
})()
```

But problem is that I cant define a function to count specific hours . Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: So wait, what is your issue? Is your total accumulating properly or are you stuck writing a function to pull specific hours? Can you clarify what you are actually asking for?

Comment: Can you include a mock array in your question so that it's easier for us to write/test a solution?

Comment: @TylerRoper The only relevant value in a "day" is `y`, hence... `Array.from({length: 27}).map(x => Array.from({length: 24}).map((x, i) => ({y: (i+1)})))`

Comment: @Andreas You have to sum the values *by hour*. I feel that breaking apart the date object into an hour-by-hour summary is a fundamental piece of the solution, no?

Comment: From the description (_"So 24 hours and 24 values for each array of object"_) and the screenshot I get the impression that the values are always "sorted" from 0 to 23.

Comment: @Andreas Assuming they're always sorted, then yes, the array index could be used in place of the hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by replacing the inner loop with a statement like this:

```
total += day[2].y
```

At the end of the loop, the total will contain the total `2AM` hours for the month.

And to get the average, divide the `total` by the total number of days of that month.

Here is a complete example:

```
const countHours = (hourOfDay) => {
    let total = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++) {
       const day = arrayOfDays[i]
       total += day[hourOfDay].y
    }
    return total / arrayOfDays.length;
}
```

In this example I'm assuming that `arrayOfDays` contains the data for only one month.

Comment: @Andreas I've copied OP's answer and didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapOfHours = arrayOfDays.reduce((sum, day) => {
   day.forEach(hour => {
      const hourX = hour.x.getHours();
      const hourY = hour.y;
      sum[hourX] = (sum[hourX] || 0) + hourY; 
   });
   return sum;
}, {});

console.log(mapOfHours);
```

---

Fastest implementation i could think of

```
const mapOfHours = {};
for(let i=0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
    const currentDay = arrayOfDays[i];
    for(let j=0; j < currentDay.length; j++){
        const hour = currentDay[j];
        const hourX = hour.x.getHours();
        const hourY = hour.y;
        mapOfHours[hourX] = (sum[hourX] || 0) + hourY; 
    }
}

console.log(mapOfHours);
```

Comment: It works fine , but is that possible to use instead of reduce method "for loop" iterator. Reduce 10 times slower than for loop  . I have 24 000 items in array , so I need as fast as possible. I tried to change it , but with no success

Comment: Updated with for loop